# pip install fails - ERROR: IPython requires Python version 2.7 or 3.3 or above

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-2.6

I installed pip today on centos 6.4 and I've tried installing python libraries via pip.

But, I got the following error.

```
ERROR: IPython requires Python version 2.7 or 3.3 or above.
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: IPython requires Python version 2.7 or 3.3 or above.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_username/ipython
Storing debug log for failure in /home/username/.pip/pip.log
```

Although the error message says I need Python version 2.7 or above, I have installed python 2.7 already.

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

I'm not sure if it's causing this problem that I have python2.6 in "usr/bin/python".

```
$ sudo python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561088/how-to-get-pip-to-point-to-newer-version-of-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two Pythons, you may have two `pip`s as well. This most probably means that you are running pip from the Python 2.6 distribution. If you will run the Python 2.7 version it will most definitely use Python 2.7. If you have only Python 2.6 version, you have to install pip again, separately for the 2.7 version.

Command that worked, posted by OP in the comments section:

```
curl -kL raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget (and this might be obscure), that if you run "sudo pip install" you might get a DIFFERENT pip than if you are running non-sudo.